# how to export the converted datatable to textfile in web application using mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, file-io, stream, export

I using the mvc format program. i have list of the value in my data table. I convert this data-table --> text file using the stream-writer . But I don't know how its through the client for download option my sample code is give below, Please suggest your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Refer Important part of code:**

```
public void ExportDataTabletoFile(DataTable datatable, string delimited, bool exportcolumnsheader, string file)

{

    StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter(file, false, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

    if (exportcolumnsheader)

    {

        string Columns = string.Empty;

        foreach (DataColumn column in datatable.Columns)

        {

            Columns += column.ColumnName + delimited;

        }

        str.WriteLine(Columns.Remove(Columns.Length - 1, 1));

    }

    foreach (DataRow datarow in datatable.Rows)

    {

        string row = string.Empty;



        foreach (object items in datarow.ItemArray)

        {



            row += items.ToString() + delimited;

        }

        str.WriteLine(row.Remove(row.Length - 1, 1));



    }

    str.Flush();

    str.Close();



}
```

**Referance Link:**

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd19b9/how-to-download-datatable-to-text-file-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Thanks for reply. Its right i have all values in my stream but its not through the file for user. I think my error in format of the through file is wrong please refer the format